# DLNA FLAC audio client which will work headless on Linux?

Tags: linux, upnp, dlna, flac

Subject line says it -- can anyone point me to a DLNA audio player client which will play FLAC without transcoding, which doesn't require an X server or graphical interface, and will run happily from the commandline?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for something similar too. The only thing similar to this is gmediarenderer but I couldn't see a way to install it on a box without X libraries installed - but I could be wrong. It is also not maintained... a fork is available at https://github.com/hzeller/gmrender-resurrect and may be worth a try.

FWIW, mpd (http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki) does operate headlessly and does everything I want except support control from my Upnp control point.